# side effects of arguments of a function

Tags: c

Here is a recursive code using side effects in function argument.In K&R, i found a statement 
saying C standard specifies that all side effects on arguments take effect before a function is called(page no.54 K&R second edition).But output to above code was contradictory.Could anyone help me out.

```
void reverse(int* array,int i,int j)
{
  `int temp;
  if(i>j)

    return ;
  else{
    temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[j];
    array[j]=temp;
    //i++;
    //j--;
    reverse(array,i++,j--);
  }
} '
```

PS:Output is segmentation fault

Comment: If your question's been answered, then please mark it as such.

Comment: It is just a really bad idea to programm with side effects. There is no functional reason to write things like this, just don't do it.

Comment: @JensGustedt, well, he's learning from K&R, and use of pre- and postfix operators is ubiquitous both there and in C overall. Still, since his function is recursive and doesn't depend on the previous value of the counter variables once a new recursive function call frame is established, I agree he should just use `i + 1` and `j - 1`.

Comment: @GregE. or just leave the `++` operations before the call as they appear in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all side effects are completed, so the value of i and j is changed before function call.

but the value of express `i++` and `j--` are still  the value of i and j previously.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the variables get incremented before the function call, but those variables are local to the function in which they're declared (in this case, one recursive function call frame), and when you use the postfix operators, the value returned by the operators is not the updated value but rather the initial value. Consequently, the values that you end up passing as parameters are not properly updated and your function will never terminate. In order to increment the variables and simultaneously return and pass-in the updated values, you have to use prefix operators, i.e., `++i` and `++j`.